# Copy a visio page to a new document

Tags: c#, office-interop, visio

**What I want to accomplish:**
I want to copy the active page in my Visio application to a new document and save it (and make it a `byte[]` for the db), I am already doing this but in a slightly "wrong" way as there is too much interaction with the Visio application.

**Method to copy page to byte array:**

```
private static byte[] VisioPageToBytes()
{
    //Make a new invisible app to dump the shapes in
    var app = new InvisibleApp();

    Page page = MainForm.IVisioApplication.ActivePage;
    app.AlertResponse = 2;

    //Selact all shapes and copy, then deselect
    MainForm.IVisioApplication.ActiveWindow.SelectAll();
    MainForm.IVisioApplication.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
    MainForm.IVisioApplication.ActiveWindow.DeselectAll();

    //Add empty document to invisible app and dump shapes
    app.Documents.Add( string.Empty );
    app.ActivePage.Paste();

    //Save document and convert to byte[]
    app.ActiveDocument.SaveAs( Application.UserAppDataPath + @"/LastStored.vsd" );
    app.ActiveDocument.Close();
    app.Quit();
    app.AlertResponse = 0;
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes( Application.UserAppDataPath + @"/LastStored.vsd" );
    Clipboard.Clear();
    return bytes;
}
```

**Why it's wrong:**
This code makes selections in the visio page and has to open an invisible window to store the page. I'm looking for a way with less interaction with the Visio application (as its unstable). The opening of the 2nd (invisible) Visio application occasionally makes my main Visio application crash.

**I would like to do something like:**

```
Page page = MainForm.IVisioApplication.ActivePage;
Document doc;
doc.Pages.Add( page ); //Pages.Add has no parameters so this doesn't work
doc.SaveAs(Application.UserAppDataPath + @"/LastStored.vsd");
```

If this is not possible in a way with less interaction (by "building" the document), please comment to let me know.

**TL;DR;**
I wan't to make a new Visio document without opening Visio and copy (the content of) 1 page to it.

Comment: Are you using the the Visio Drawing Control in a form or a standalone application?  If it's the former then the control only allows one document to be open at a time.  Also, is there a reason why you don't want to just SaveAs and then delete other pages?

Comment: Not a drawing control, an application. If you look at the code you can see I make an invisible application, this can't be done with a drawing control

Comment: @JohnGoldsmith I'm doing things (storing) with the data on each page, after that we want to keep a copy of just that page in the database so I store it and save it to the database as a byte array. If I can make a copy of the document and remove the pages without opening them in a visio application post that as an answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a copy page then you might find the [Duplicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228005.aspx) method on Page handy, but by the sounds of it just save the existing doc should work:

```
void Main()
{
    var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();

    var sourcePage = vApp.ActivePage;
    var sourcePageNameU = sourcePage.NameU;
    var vDoc = sourcePage.Document;
    vDoc.Save(); //to retain original
    var origFileName = vDoc.FullName;

    var newFileName = Path.Combine(vDoc.Path, $"LastStored{Path.GetExtension(origFileName)}");
    vDoc.SaveAs(newFileName);

    //Remove all other pages
    for (short i = vDoc.Pages.Count; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (vDoc.Pages[i].NameU != sourcePageNameU)
        {
            vDoc.Pages[i].Delete(0);
        }
    }

    //Save single page state
    vDoc.Save();

    //Close copy and reopen original
    vDoc.Close();
    vDoc = vApp.Documents.Open(origFileName);
}
```

`GetRunningVisio` is my extension method for using with LinqPad:

http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2015/12/getting-started-with-c-in-linqpad-with-visio.html

...but you've already got a reference to your app so you can use that instead.

**Update based on comments:**

Ok, so how about this modification of your original code?  Note that I'm creating a new Selection object from the page but not changing the Window one, so this shouldn't interfere with what the user sees or change the source doc at all.

```
void Main()
{
    var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();

    var sourcePage = vApp.ActivePage;
    var sourceDoc = sourcePage.Document;
    var vSel = sourcePage.CreateSelection(Visio.VisSelectionTypes.visSelTypeAll);
    vSel.Copy(Visio.VisCutCopyPasteCodes.visCopyPasteNoTranslate);

    var copyDoc = vApp.Documents.AddEx(string.Empty,
                         Visio.VisMeasurementSystem.visMSDefault,
                         (int)Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visAddHidden);
    copyDoc.Pages[1].Paste(Visio.VisCutCopyPasteCodes.visCopyPasteNoTranslate);

    var origFileName = sourceDoc.FullName;
    var newFileName = Path.Combine(sourceDoc.Path, $"LastStored{Path.GetExtension(origFileName)}");
    copyDoc.SaveAs(newFileName);
    copyDoc.Close();
}
```

Note that this will only create a default page so you might want to include copying over page cells such as PageWidth, PageHeight, PageScale and DrawingScale etc. prior to pasting.

Comment: The existing doc has 40 pages, I only want to save 1 :)

Comment: And the duplicate method on a page duplicates the page within the current document where work is still being performed on. I want it separate from the current doc/application